# Какой график применить для контроля рабочего времени в Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, график

```
    for contour in contours:
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)

        if cv2.contourArea(contour) < 2000:
            continue
        cv2.rectangle(roi, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.putText(roi, "{}".format(" M"), (10, 150), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                    1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
```

Это часть кода, но она самая главная в этом процессе, так как от ее зависит вывод информации о движения в кадре видеокамеры. Она рисует прямоугольник в кадре вокруг например человека или авто, в общем вокруг движущего объекта, который часто применяются в видеонаблюдении как детектор движения.
Теперь нужно зафиксировать это на графике, например, как отчет о присутствии рабочего на рабочем месте, т.е. есть человек, есть движение, записываем в график, нет движения - график стоит, и опять есть движение, фиксируем в график и нет движения - не фиксируем.... Вопрос, как это сделать в графике matplotlib, или просто в .txt, или в turtle можно. Пробовал многое, но так как мало опыта в программировании, нужна помощь. Буду благодарен всем!

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот примерно так выглядят первые наброски.

Comment: В matplotlib есть такая штука - анимированный график называется. https://wiki.programstore.ru/python-animirovannye-grafiki/  Специально для подобных задач.

Comment: Да по ссылке готовый пример есть. Только вместо описанной там -  подставляете вашу функцию, которая возвращает сигнал (флажок присутствия- отсутствия, координаты или что там у вас), за что тут деньги-то брать?

Comment: Абсолютно исключено!

Comment: Можно фиксировать движения в области roi с помощью contour? При движении он выдает двумерный массив,  это координаты прямоугольника, который рисует вокруг человека, при обнаружении. Можно перевести этот массив в число, например datetime, и уже записывать в часах, минутах?

Comment: Во-первых, если есть уже двухмерный массив координат, то зачем его переводить в одно число?  Во-вторых, к этому массиву координат время  я бы добавлял, а не "превращал".

Comment: Отлично!Не пойму один момент!!! Я добавил разницу(дельту) по времени, между настоящим временем и начало рабочего дня, разница фиксируется в графике,  есть движение, она пишет в график  время, когда нет движения не пишет, НО когда после паузы опять начинает писать по движению, время где оно остановилось настигает настоящее и весь график разницы по времени теряет смысл...

Comment: мне нужна фиксация рабочего момента и момента паузы, т.е. например, человек работал возле станка 3 часа, отходил покурить, пописать в течении смены 10 минут...

Comment: здесь нужно прописать условия?

Comment: Прописывайте метки  времени, а не дельты. И никто никого не будет "достигать".

Answer (score -1):

Отказался я от времени(datetime) и применил круговой график(pie). В rectangle поставил метку в виде определенного числа, и теперь при сработке движения есть время работы сотрудника, а при его отсутствии время стоит

Comment: посмотрите ещё тип графика "диаграмма Гантта"

Comment: Благодарю за информацию, она очень полезная!